# Python script crashes randomly for unknown reason

Tags: python, logging, mqtt, gateway

I am using the following script as the basis for a homebuilt energy monitoring system. The script serves as a gateway between an arduino based receiver connected to the serial port and passes it on through MQTT as well as a http POST. The script is intended to run indefinitely. However it crashes at random intervals, anywhere from an hour to a week. I cannot figure out why. Any pointers on how to determine why and how to log the error would be appreciated. Here is the script:

```
import time
import datetime
import requests
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
#import csv
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR, filename='serial-read.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

device = '/dev/ttyUSB0' #this will have to be changed to the serial port you are using
data = ""
pieces = ""

while True:
    while True:
        try:
            receiver = serial.Serial(device, 57600)
            receiver.flushInput()
        except serial.SerialException:
            print "cannot connect. will try again..."
            time.sleep(10)
        else:
            break
    try:
        data = receiver.readline()
        #print (data)
        #print repr(data)
        #with open ("data_log.csv","a") as f:
            #writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
            #writer.writerow([time.time(),data])
        pieces = data.split(" ")
        try:
            nodeid = int(pieces[0])
        except ValueError:
            pass
        try:
            data1 = int(pieces[1])
            data2 = int(pieces[2])
            data3 = int(pieces[3])
            data4 = int(pieces[4])
        except IndexError:
            pass
        #print nodeid
        if nodeid == 6:
            #print "Power:"
            Irms = data3 + data4
            print Irms
            localtime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            localtime = "'" + localtime + "'"
            #print localtime
            payload = {"timestamp" : localtime, "Irms" : Irms}
            r = requests.post('http://www.********.ca/*****.php', params=payload)
            #print(r.url)
            publish.single("myHome/energy/power", Irms, hostname="192.168.1.120")
        elif nodeid == 2:
            temp = float(data1)/10
            #print "temp:"
            #print temp
            hum = data3
            publish.single("myHome/garage/temperature", temp, hostname="192.168.1.120")
            publish.single("myHome/garage/humidity", hum, hostname="192.168.1.120")
            temphum = str(temp) + " " + str(hum)
            publish.single("myHome/garage/temphum", temphum, hostname="192.168.1.120")
            #print temphum
    except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
        print "no device connected. Please reconnect device..."
        receiver.close()
        time.sleep(5)
```

Thank you!

Baobab

Comment: What's the error when it crashes?

Comment: I don't know - that's the problem. Most likely an issue with the data coming in through the serial port thus my attempt to handle those errors - but that is just a guess. Not sure how I would set up the error logging to save any and all errors to the log file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second `try` statement catches the following exception:

```
except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
```

But what if the block of code generates a different exception? The script will exit. Add a second `except`, as in the first `try` loop, to catch any other exceptions, and print them to your log.